# Excel: How to reference a lookup array range (in another cell) with the Index-Match function pair?

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, range, match

Question: how (if possible) can I reference a lookup array range, i.e.,

```
MATCH($H$3,**[reference another cell]:$M$30**,0)]
```

Can I reference another cell containing `G10` to replace the lower bounds?

Or a cell containing a new range `G10:G20`?

I want to return multiple values from a collection of data. To get the first value I have been using index-match:

```
=INDEX($D$31:$M$1005,MATCH(E4,(G31:G1005),0),MATCH($H$3,$D$30:$M$30,0))
```

I want to use a helper column to first reference the row the returned value from the initial index-match function (i.e. the returned $10 stock price is in row `G100`). Then for the second index-match function, I want to alter the array of the arrays in the index-match function so that it will start looking for the next value in a new array that starts below the row # of the initial value.

Comment: Look into the INDIRECT() function. `INDEX(INDIRECT("G10:G20"), 3, 4)` would work and can be replaced with `INDEX(INDIRECT(G100), 3, 4)`

Comment: This does not seem to work, It does not create a new lookup array. Where: =INDEX($D$31:$M$1005,MATCH(E4,INDIRECT(B4,TRUE):G1005),0),MATCH($H$3,$D$30:$M$30,0))  and Cell B4 contains "G239".

Comment: `B4,TRUE` isn't a string that represents a range address. Please read up on the INDIRECT() function.